# Use CloudKit with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icloud, cloudkit

I am wondering if it's possible to use CloudKit with React Native? I would like to allow users to login with their iTunes account in React Native, or just easily grab their User Record name if they are already logged in with iCloud for seamless auth.

Is this possible? Havn't seen it mentioned anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Like most things that are platform/hardware specific, it looks like you're going to have to write a wrapper in order to use CloudKit with React Native. If you're just trying to wrap the login/auth status, it should be relatively simple to accomplish. [This guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) is a pretty good start to wrapping native code to be used in React Native.